# Convert MySQL date format to DD/MM/YY date format using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how I would go about converting the SQL timestamp format (2016-04-30T01:19:45.000Z) to a standard date format like (30/04/2016) using Javascript/front-end-technology.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: first do this `var d = new Date(mysqldate)`  do this `d.getDate()` which return date of month  than `d.getMonth()` and than get year with `d.getFullYear()`

Comment: i hope this work it's plain js

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hope this helps. This can be achieved in multiple ways - pure JavaScript, jQuery, Angular etc., As well it requires bit of tweaking based on your requirement. Do let me know if this helps

```
<script>
        var myDate = new Date('2010-10-11T00:00:00+05:30');
        alert((myDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + myDate.getDate() + '/' + myDate.getFullYear());
    </script>
```

Comment: Incredible! Thank you! :)

Comment: my bootstrap datepicker didn't like the dates unless they were padded with leading zeros. I modified your solution which solved my issue. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on how many operations you want to do. If it is more than one, then i would recommend using a library like momentJS. It makes timestamp conversion very simple. See example below.

MySQL date string:

```
var sqlDate = new Date('2016-04-30T01:19:45.000z');
var now = moment(sqlDate).format('l');
console.log( now );
```

Comment: Thanks! I've got quite a few libraries running already because I've been getting a bit lazy so I'm trying to avoid anymore - but regardless thank you for your response. :)